# Not displaying employee name & date in php page

Tags: php

In DB, when i run below query in phpmyadmin, i got perfect result :

[image]

but in php page, its display as below  without displaying **employee name & date** :

[image]

```
$sql = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, COUNT(*) 
as count FROM orders WHERE employeename in ('nawaz' , 'asha') 
AND DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
 GROUP BY employeename, date"; 
$results = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sql); 
$numrowsresult =$results[0]['count'];       

foreach ($results as $result) 
{

    echo $result['count']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `echo $result['count']` ... because you only `echo` the count

Comment: So `echo` these fields.

Comment: sorry , i am still beginner and learning.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `echo` these fields as well :)

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
{  
    echo $result['employeename']."<br>";
    echo $result['date']."<br>";
    echo $result['count']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I wanted result for all the employees, so i used this code : `$sql = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, COUNT(*) 
as count FROM orders  
AND DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
 GROUP BY employeename, date"; ` but it gave syntax error, please tell me what is the error.....

Comment: use this: `$sql = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, COUNT(*) as count FROM orders WHERE DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY employeename, date";`

Comment: You need to put `WHERE` instead of `AND` after `select ... FROM orders`

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the empname and date. please try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, COUNT(*) 
    as count FROM orders WHERE employeename in ('nawaz' , 'asha') 
    AND DATE(reattemptdate) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
     GROUP BY employeename, date"; 
    $results = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sql); 
    $numrowsresult =$results[0]['count'];       

    foreach ($results as $result) 
    {

        echo $result['count'].'-'.$result['employeename'].'-'.$result['date']."<br>";
    }
```